# Grouped CollectionView With Horizontal Orientation In Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

[image: Issue Displaying Second Grouped Items][image: Grouped CollectionView Display]

I have checked on collectionview property  i was trying to display grouped collection view with horizontal orientation ,i got into issue the grouped items are also displaying in horizontal view. can any one help me on resolving issue or any suggestion on implementing like shared image  **

Comment: It's insane that this is the default behavior for grouped items in a CollectionView... no one anywhere, in any situation, ever, would want this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**  You could create a CollectionView in each cell .

**Option 2:**  It would be better to use **BindableLayout**

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

      <DataTemplate>

           <ScrollView BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}" Orientation="Horizontal">

                // set items here 

            </ScrollView>

      </DataTemplate>

</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

For more details you could check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) .

Comment: Zhang Please find the attached image ,my second grouped items  are also appearing  horizontally Instead of Appearing in next row

Comment: Did you  check my solution ? I think it could implement it .

Comment: Set the Orientation of CollectionView as vertical .

Comment: Zhang .. Thank you so much..it really worked for me. thanks for helping me :) i will post as repo so that it will help someone

Comment: @Divya Can you share the repo link?

Comment: I don't understand how this would work.  `ItemTemplate` is the template for individual items. We want to wrap entire groups of items into single `ScrollView`s, not have one `ScrollView` per item...

Comment: @Chitu After lots of experimentation, I'm almost certain this answer is wrong. I think what Lucas was suggesting was turning `IsGrouped="False"` and then having each group as its own item. This will allow you to display the groups correctly, but it completely breaks the `CollectionView`'s ability to select individual items, since one "item" is an entire group.  And if you're not using the selection, the `CollectionView` is completely pointless to begin with.